# Raspberry Pi B can be seen on LAN but no Video output on either HDMI or RCA

Tags: raspbmc, hdmi, video

My Raspberry Pi B running RaspBMC recently stopped working, I found that the SDCard had died.  I rebuilt a new SDCard with the latest RaspBMC download.  The LEDs on the Pi all illuminate, I can see the Pi on My LAN and I can access it using WinSCP and see the folder structure over the LAN but I don't get any video output on either HDMI or RCA trying on multiple TVs and monitors.

I have rebuilt the SDCard a few times and finally used the SDCard/USB combination also without success.

I have edited the config.txt file to force the video to HDMI without any success.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Without details of your monitor or current `config.txt` it is difficult to comment. http://elinux.org/RPiconfig#Video_mode_options shows possible settings. You can `ssh` into the Pi andd display current mode with `sudo /opt/vc/bin/tvservice -s`